# Text (Absolute) Will Not Pass Through Vertical Scroll Bar

Tags: html, css

Currently I have a sidebar on my website, and when a user hovers something on the sidebar it should bring up a popover. Yet there is this really weird issue!

The sidebar has a vertical scroll bar, and when the popover comes up it will not go over the scroll bar. Here is a image of it (Please note that is not going to be the actual popover, it is just for testing):

[image: Before and After Scroll Bar]
Sorry, not sure why the text is appearing down here. Anyhow as you can see when there is a scroll bar the text will not pass through it, yet when the scroll bar is removed the text WILL pass through it. Here is all of the important CSS:

```
.sidebarbuttons2    {
    width: 100%;
    height: 5%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: gray;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 70%;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #474747;
    z-index: 2;
}

.sidebarbuttons2 li .dropdownbuttonsholder  {
    display: none;                          
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; 
  margin-left:150px;
  float:left;
  margin-top: -45px;
  height: 0;
    z-index: 3;
}               

.sidebarbuttons2 li:hover .dropdownbuttonsholder    {
    width: 200px;
    background-color: blue;
    border: 1px solid black;
    list-style: none;
    height: 25px;
    display: block;
    z-index: 4000;
    position: absolute;
}

#dropdownbuttonitem1 {
    background-color: red;
    height: 25px;
    z-index: 5;
}

#dropdownbuttonitem2 {
    background-color: green;
    height: 25px;
    z-index: 5;
}

#dropdownbuttonitem3 {
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 25px;
    z-index: 5;
}

#dropdownbuttonitem4 {
    background-color: orange;
    height: 25px;
    z-index: 5;
}

/*-------------------------------------------------------*/
/*Sidebar Style*/
/*-------------------------------------------------------*/

.sidebarpostinbutton {
    color: orange;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#sidebar {
    width: 20%;
    height: 1900px;
    background-color: gray;
    z-index: 1;
    border-right: 3px solid #474747;
    position: absolute;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    font-size: 88%;
}

#sidebar:hover {
    width: 25%;
    z-index: 5;
    -webkit-transition: 1s linear;
    -moz-transition: 1s linear;
    -o-transition: 1s linear;
    -ms-transition: 1s linear;
    transition: 1s linear;
}

.sidebarbuttons {
    width: 100%;
    height: 5%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: gray;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 70%;
    line-height: 0%;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #474747;
}

#sidebarbuttonlast1 {
    border-bottom: 0px;
}

#sidebarscrollinformation {
    display: none;
}

/*-------------------------------------------------------*/
/*Main Contents Box Style*/
/*-------------------------------------------------------*/

.maincontentssection {
    background-color: lightgray;
    margin-left: 20%;
    height: 1900px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 80%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

And then here is the important HTML:

```
<div id="sidebar">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-12">
        <ul class="nav sidebarbuttons2"> <!-- navbar -->
            <li><a href="#"> <h1> Art </h1> </a>
                <ul class="dropdownbuttonsholder row">
                    <ul id="dropdownbuttonitem1" class="col-xs-3"><a href="#"> All Posts </a></ul>
                    <ul id="dropdownbuttonitem2" class="col-xs-3"><a href="#"> Most Popular </a></ul>
                    <ul id="dropdownbuttonitem3" class="col-xs-3"><a href="#"> Most Viewed </a></ul>
                    <ul id="dropdownbuttonitem4" class="col-xs-3"><a href="#"> Newest </a></ul>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I can not figure out why it is not going through the scroll bar. Please Help! :)

P.S. If you would like the full HTML go here: http://pastebin.com/c89M7MPk (it is a include), and the full CSS go here: http://pastebin.com/yJZp9HT2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's just how `overflow: scroll` works. Even if you use `overflow-x` or `overflow-y`, you cannot mix this with `overflow: visible` in the same element.

The only thing you can do, is to use `overflow-x: visible; overflow-y: hidden;` for the CSS, and use javascript to scroll the element. Check out a library like this for the scroll: http://darsa.in/sly/

Answer (score 0):

In the CSS, LINE 974 change margin-left:150px; to margin-left: 0px;

Comment: Yes, that would work to show what is there currently. But the actual popover will be much bigger, and it will end up having to flow over the scroll bar (which it currently will not).

Comment: Oh, well then I'm not sure, but one suggestion, wouldn't it be more clean for it to drop down within the scroll bar?